# Existence of partial derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$f(x,y) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{x^2}{x^2 + y^2} &, (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\ 
 0&, (x,y) = (0,0)
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

Questions:

1. $f_x(x,y)$
2. $f_y(x,y)$
3. $f_{yx}(0,0)$

How can i solve this question?

Comment: Are you having problem with 1 and 2? For 1, fix $y$, differentiate with respect to $x$. Only the case $(x,y)=(0,0)$ is annoying.

Comment: Im having problem with all of them.They're not clear for me.If I see the solution I think I can get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for (1), you'll treat $y$ like it's a constant, then take the derivative with respect to $x$ (applying quotient rule) to get $f_x(x,y)$ for $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$. Also, $$f_x(0,0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}$$ is undefined, so $f_x$ is undefined everywhere but at the origin.

We'll do something similar for (2), but this time we treat $x$ as a constant and take the derivative with respect to $y$ to find $f_y(x,y)$ for $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$, then use $$f_y(0,0)=\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{f(0,k)-f(0,0)}{k},$$ which actually **does** exist, so $f_y$ is defined everywhere. (Hover over the blank spot below to see how $f_y$ is defined as a piecewise function.)

> $$f_y(x,y)=\begin{cases}-\dfrac{2x^2y}{(x^2+y^2)^2} & (x,y)\neq(0,0)\\0 & (x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$$

For (3), we'll use our answer from (2), and proceed in the same way we did in (1), treating $y$ as a constant and taking the derivative of $f_y(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ to get $f_{yx}(x,y)$ for $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$, then finding $$f_{yx}(0,0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f_y(h,0)-f_y(0,0)}{h}.$$

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you want to calculate those quantities. For points besides $(0,0),$ there's nothing unusual to consider. At $(0,0)$, you'll need the limit definition of the partial derivative. For example, in number 1, look at

$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\frac{(x+h)^2}{(x+h)^2+0^2}-0}{h}.$

The second derivative will also require the limit definition at the origin. Let me know if you figure out the first two, and we'll go from there.

Comment: $f_x = 0$ Is it correct?

Comment: Nope, try again. Did you try evaluating the limit above? It looks pretty straightforward.

Comment: Can you evaluate them?

Comment: $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\frac{(x+h)^2}{(x+h)^2+0^2}-0}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1-0}{h}$ is the first one.

Answer (score 0):

1) $f_x(x,y)$ just means the partial derivative w.r.t $x$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=-\frac{2xy^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$

2) $f_y(x,y)$ is then the partil derivative w.r.t $y$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=-\frac{2yx^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$

3) $f_{yx}$ is the first partial derivative w.r.t $y$, and then w.r.t $x$. But now we are evaluating this derivative in $(0,0)$. Can you come up with the derivative?

Comment: All this is true at $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$. The main trick here is the $(0,0)$ case. Even for 1) and 2). It exists for $\partial y$, not for $\partial x$.